# Proper format of json for Highchart.js with multiple series

Tags: javascript, json, charts, highcharts, series

I have examples json data for Higcharts USD currency: 
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/usdeur.json

So i added simply one value to data, there not show in a chart.

```
[
    [
        1167609600000,
        50,
        30
    ],
    [
        1167609600001,
        60,
        40
    ],
    [
        1167609600002,
        70,
        50
    ]
]
```

My code:

> function myFunction() { Highcharts.getJSON(
>   'http://192.168.0.157/log1.json',   function (data) {
>
> ```
> Highcharts.chart('container', {
>   chart: {
>     zoomType: 'x',        backgroundColor:"#e7ecea" 
>   },
>   title: {
>     text: 'Pomiary'
>   },
>   subtitle: {
>     text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
>       'select' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
>   },
>   xAxis: {
>     type: 'datetime'
>   },
>   yAxis: {
>     title: {
>       text: 'Exchange rate'
>     }
>   },
>   legend: {
>     enabled: false
>   },
>   plotOptions: {
>     area: {
>       fillColor: {
>
>         stops: [
>           [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
>           [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
>         ]
>       },
>       marker: {
>         radius: 2
>       },
>       lineWidth: 1,
>       states: {
>         hover: {
>           lineWidth: 1
>         }
>       },
>       threshold: null
>     }
>   },
>
>   series: [{
>     type: 'area',
>     name: 'speed',
>     data: data
>   },    {
>     type: 'area',
>     name: 'speed2',
>     data: data
>   }]
> });   } );
> ```
>
> };

How i can add next series?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use `keys` property:

```
series: [{
  data: data
}, {
  keys: ['x', 'someValue', 'y'],
  data: data
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4797/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys